'ReactSVG' cannot be used as a JSX component
I'm getting on my first React/Next.js project and i need to import an SVG file and modify it before rendering.
I tried to find some modules that let me do that and i settled on react-svg https://github.com/tanem/react-svg/
and in development everything works as needed.
The problem came when i'm trying to suppress the warnings and the errors that came from ESLINT trying to deploy.
I'm using ReactSVG like this:
'use client'

import { ReactSVG } from "react-svg";

...

const Page = () => {

...

const attachTurnsToSvg = (elements = []) => {
 elements.forEach((element: SVGRectElement) => {
  //insert text inside SVGelements
 });
};

    const attachCallsToSvg = (elements = []) => {
        elements.forEach((element: SVGCircleElement) => {
            element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                console.debug('clicked', e);
            });
        });
    };

return(
<>
...
                <ReactSVG
                    src="/mysvg.svg" 
                    beforeInjection={(svg) => {
                        const svgWidth = (width !== undefined ? 0.625 * width : 1200);
                        const svgHeight = (height !== undefined ? 0.88 * height : 800);
                        svg.setAttribute('style', `width: ${svgWidth}px; height: ${svgHeight}px;`);
                      }}
                    afterInjection={(svg: { querySelectorAll: (arg0: string) => never[]; }) => {
                        const rects = svg?.querySelectorAll('rect.turnRect') || [];
                        attachTurnsToSvg(rects);
                        const circles = svg?.querySelectorAll('circle.callCircle') || [];
                        attachCallsToSvg(circles);
                    }}
                    className={styles.map} 
                />
</>)
}

export default Page;

and everything seems to works fine in development, however i got the errors:
"JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.",
'ReactSVG' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type 'typeof ReactSVG' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type 'typeof ReactSVG' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => Component<any, any, any>'.
Type 'ReactSVG' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<any, any, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, refs
and can't build the app.
Everything else works as i intended and i can't seem to find another solution to make it work...

I would recommend defining your own SVG component as it will make customizing it much easier in the future. Extract the content from your SVG (and if possible, transform the repeating elements into a map loop).
For example:
import { Fragment } from 'react';

const circles = [{ cy: 20, cx: 20, fill: "red", ...otherProps }, ... otherCircles];
const rects = [{ y: 0, x: 0, textToInsert: "Hello", ...otherProps }, ...otherRects];

export default function MySVG() {
   return <svg width={1200} height={800}>
      {circles.map((circleProps, idx) => <circle {...circleProps} key={idx} className="callCircle" onClick={(e) => console.log("clicked", e)} />)}
      {rects.map(({ textToInsert, ...rectProps }, idx) => <Fragment key={idx}>
         <rect {...rectProps} key={idx} className="turnRect" onClick={(e) => console.log("clicked", e)} />
         { /* You cannot insert a SVG text inside a rect, but you can overlay it */ }
         <text x={rectProps.x} y={rectProps.y}>{textToInsert}</text>
      </Fragment>)}
   </svg>
}

import MySVG from "./MySVG.tsx";

const Page = () => {
   return <MySVG />;
}

export default Page;

This may not be an ideal solution for your use case, but this approach will allow you much more customisation of your SVGs while having a more "React-y" approach instead of using native JS querySelectors which are computed after the initial render.
However, if you are required to modify preexisting SVGs in your use case, you can do so using native JS in a useEffect. For example:
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import MySvg from "/mysvg.svg"; // use SVGR or babel-plugin-inline-react-svg to directly render an inline SVG

export default function Page() {
   const svgRef = useRef(null);

   useEffect(() => {
     if (svgRef.current) {
        const rects = svgRef.current.querySelectorAll('rect.turnRect') || [];
        // do stuff with rects
        const circles = svgRef.current.querySelectorAll('circle.callCircle') || [];
        // do stuff with circles
     }
   }, [svgRef.current])

   return <MySvg ref={svgRef} height={800} width={1200} />
}

You can find tutorials online to setup SVGR or a similar SVG parser into your NextJS project.
I hope this helped. Do not hesitate to comment to ask further questions :) !

Remember to give all those mapped elements key attributes. The console should be glowing yellow with warnings about the code you're suggesting here because React can't efficiently diff without them =)

Wow! Thank you! You helped me clearing my thoughts about using SVGs in React.
I really liked the first solution, but unfortunately i have to use preexisting SVGs for a cost reduction POV.
I'm trying to implement the second solution you generously provided, but I have a doubt about a couple of things: can i use the code directly in my final page or should i create a component and import it? and how can i refer to "/mysvg.svg"?; the direct import cast some errors, while using it as a src attribute, from the root /public (a sibling of /src/app) seems fine.
Thanks a lot again for your answer!

@user24350722 You can directly import your SVG with a relative import (relative to the page file itself) once you have installed SVGR webpack for nextJS (https://github.com/platypusrex/next-plugin-svgr). If you have Typescript complaining, you can add a svg.d.ts shim like this
declare module '*.svg' {
const content: any;
export const ReactComponent: any;
export default content;
}
and import it in tsconfig. I would advise you to follow a SVGR tutorial. If you have any remaining question about SVGR, do open a new question and comment with the link so I can reply to you further

By the way do not forget to mark the question as resolved if it helped :)

Thanks again! I'm gonna mark it as resolved!
Anyway, for complete solution, we couldn't use ref={svgRef} cause it cast an error: function components cannot be given refs, so i managed to create a component by using this tool and pasting my Svg in it, in order to convert it https://react-svgr.com/playground/?dimensions=false&expandProps=start&jsxRuntime=automatic&ref=true
Then i could use it as intended!
Again thank you very much!
